# UInavigatonbar items

Tags: ios

I add a `uinavigationcontroller` as a `subview` on a `uiviewcontroller` (rootviewcontroller of aap) and this view controller is a `subview` as a `rootviewcontroller` on self.window.
in Appdelegate I use:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.rootVC;
```

and in `viewdidload` of my `RootViewController` I wrote:

```
    [self.navVC.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    [self.navVC.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
    self.navVC.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    [app.rootVC.view addSubview:self.navVC.view];
    self.navVC.delegate = self;
```

Here, `navigationbar` is displaying but I am unable to display `uibarbutton` items on navigation bar. Example code:

```
 leftBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Left" style:UIBar
 flxBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBa
 rightBtn1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Right" style:UIBar
 rightBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Right" style:UIBar


 [self.navVC.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftBtn];
 [self.navVC.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:@[rightbtn1,rightbtn,flxBtn]];
```

Can somebody help me out to resolve my problem. How can I change appearance of `navigationbar` and how the `uibarbutton` items can be displayed ?

Answer (score 0):

You will simply need to change your

```
[self.navVC.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:@[rightbtn1,rightbtn,flxBtn]];
```

to

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:@[rightbtn1,rightbtn,flxBtn]];
```

and

```
[self.navVC.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftBtn];
```

to

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftBtn];`
```